# How to create a table from unformatted data within the browser?

Tags: javascript, formatting, tabular

I have a log file that is generated and records timestamps of utility access. The log looks similar to this

```
Fri May 27 12:43:48 PDT 2011      user1 command1 1 2 3
Fri May 27 12:43:50 PDT 2011      user1 command2 abcdef   12  11
Fri May 27 12:44:00 PDT 2011      user1 command3
Fri May 27 12:45:12 PDT 2011      user1 command4
```

I access this file through my browser to check the activity.

Since the file is a text file, is is not very easy to read.

Is it possible (using Javascript?) to modify the file after loading in the browser, so that **timestamp**, **username** and **command** are displayed in three columns of a table, and the original file is not affected?

If it matters, I am using Chrome 12, so any solution specific to the browser will also work.

Comment: How is this file served to the browser? It will be probably a neater solution to split those lines at the server side and send the table in the HTML markup.

Comment: considered using `<pre>` or just css `white-space`?

Comment: How about something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/ekctq/1/)?

Comment: @Marcel: I access the file using an apache server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a JavaScriptlet (a javascript: URL shortcut in your browser bar) that does something like this:

```
(function() {
  var lines = document.body.innerHTML.split(/\r?\n/)
    , table = "<table>", line, i;
  for (i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    line = lines[i].split(/\s+/);
    table += "<tr>";
    table += "<td>" + line.slice(0, 6).join(' ') + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + line[6] + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + line.slice(7).join(' ') + "</td>";
    table += "</tr>";
  }
  table += "</table>";
  document.body.innerHTML = table;
})();
```

So just compress that all onto a single line and save your shortcut as "`javascript:[code here]`" and it should work.  Theoretically.  I haven't tried it.